# Authenticate Active Directory users with PAM module and sshd service

Tags: rundeck, pam

I've just installed a fresh Rundeck server:

- Rundeck version: [ 4.10.1.20230221-1]
- install type: [ rpm ]
- OS Name/version: [ Oracle Linux 8 UEKR6 - Kernel 5.4.17-2136.315.5]
- DB Type/version: [postgres v13.7]

It is running behind NGINX with TLS Certificate. No issue on this.

I'm trying to setup external authentication not with the LDAP module but with the PAM module that comes with Rundeck. The server is already joined to our Active Directory domain with Winbind and Samba.

When I am trying to log with my domain user on the web UI, the Web UI display "Wrong username or password" while the logs tells the opposite.

I have edited the jaas conf file and added the Pam method

- `jaas-loginmodule.conf`

```
org.rundeck.jaas.jettyPamLoginModule requisite
      debug="true"
      service="sshd"
      supplementalRoles="readonly"
      storePass="true"

org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.PropertyFileLoginModule required
      debug="true"
      file="/etc/rundeck/realm.properties";
```

When I try to log with AD user, the rundeck service log display that it succeeded:

- `/var/log/rundeck/service.log`

```
[2023-03-08T13:35:12,068] DEBUG pam.AbstractPamLoginModule - PAM authentication trying (sshd) for: jsmith
[2023-03-08T13:35:12,416] DEBUG pam.AbstractPamLoginModule - PAM authentication succeeded for: jsmith
```

But the access logs shows the opposite:

- `/var/log/rundeck/rundeck.access.log`

```
[2023-03-08T13:35:12,068] INFO web.requests "GET /user/error" [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] http form 303 ? [] (Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36)
```

Does it success but can not login because the AD user does not exists in the Rundeck database ?

Thank you for you help

Comment: HI! When you say "Does it success but can not login because the AD user does not exists in the Rundeck database ?" do you see the "You have no authorized access to projects" message? o the acces is denied?

Comment: I see "Username or password not valid" on the Web UI.

Comment: Another question: is the file defined inside "RDpropertyfilelogin" block like [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#pam)? Could you update the full `jaas-loginmodule.conf` config file?

Comment: The full config file on my server is this:

`RDpropertyfilelogin {
org.rundeck.jaas.jettyPamLoginModule requisite
      debug="true"
      service="sshd"
      supplementalRoles="readonly"
      storePass="true";

org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.PropertyFileLoginModule required
      debug="true"
      file="/etc/rundeck/realm.properties";
};
```

while on the Rundeck documentation the PropertyFileLoginModule is different

I tried copy/paste same conf but the server does not start.

Comment: Could you try using `JettyPamLoginModule` instead of `jettyPamLoginModule`? (J in uppercase).

Comment: Which error are you seeing when you use `org.rundeck.jaas.jetty.JettyRolePropertyFileLoginModule` instead of `org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.PropertyFileLoginModule`?

Comment: The J was already in uppercase, sorry for that, i'm in air gap environment and can't copy/paste the conf, I need to write it everytime ^^

And it does not give restart error anymore if I use  `org.rundeck.jaas.jetty.JettyRolePropertyFileLoginModule`, the issue was that I did comment the line of org.eclipse, but I understand after that it does not parse the conf file if there is # in the file.

And it works now !!

I think that was the 'org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.PropertyFileLoginModule' that was causing issue. 

Or maybe the missing `useFirstPass="true"` in the module

Comment: Last thing:

- if I combine `org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.PropertyFileLoginModule` & `org.rundeck.jaas.jetty.JettyPamLoginModule` I can connect with local admin user but not domain user.

- if I combine `org.rundeck.jaas.jetty.JettyRolePropertyFileLoginModule` & `org.rundeck.jaas.jetty.JettyPamLoginModule` I can NOT connect with local admin user but I can now connect with domain user

I would like to keep local admin in case active directory becomes unavailable, or maybe this is not a best practices ?

Comment: I fix the problem, I can now login with local user and domain user.

RDpropertyfilelogin {
  org.rundeck.jaas.jetty.JettyPamLoginModule requisite
        debug="true"
        service="sshd"
        supplementalRoles="readonly"
        storePass="true";

  org.rundeck.jaas.jetty.JettyRolePropertyFileLoginModule required
        debug="true"
        useFirstPass="true"
        file="/etc/rundeck/realm.properties";
  

  org.ecliplse.jetty.jaas.spi.PropertyFileLoginModule required
        debug="true"
        file="/etc/rundeck/realm.properties";

};

Comment: Good news then, please add your solution as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Off the record answer:

It works with the followin config:

```
RDpropertyfilelogin { 
  org.rundeck.jaas.jetty.JettyPamLoginModule requisite 
    debug="true" 
    service="sshd" 
    supplementalRoles="readonly" 
    storePass="true"; 

  org.rundeck.jaas.jetty.JettyRolePropertyFileLoginModule required        
    debug="true" 
    useFirstPass="true" 
    file="/etc/rundeck/realm.properties"; 

  org.ecliplse.jetty.jaas.spi.PropertyFileLoginModule required 
    debug="true" file="/etc/rundeck/realm.properties"; 
};
```